# Make a placeable object snap to grid

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a build mechanic in my game and I was wondering how I could make it so whenever I was placing the object down it would snap to a grid. Whenever I press 0 it moves the object to my mouse and whenever I click it places the object down. I want to make it snap to a grid when placing so objects dont collide.

```css
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class GroundPlacementController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject placeableObjectPrefab;
    public NavMeshObstacle nav;


    [SerializeField]
    private KeyCode newObjectHotkey = KeyCode.A;
    
    private GameObject currentPlaceableObject;


    private float mouseWheelRotation;

    



    private void Update()
    {
        HandleNewObjectHotkey();
        nav = GetComponent<NavMeshObstacle>();
        if (currentPlaceableObject != null)
        {
            MoveCurrentObjectToMouse();
            RotateFromMouseWheel();
            ReleaseIfClicked();



        }
    }

    private void HandleNewObjectHotkey()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(newObjectHotkey))
        {
            if (currentPlaceableObject != null)
            {
                Destroy(currentPlaceableObject);
               
            }
            else
            {
                currentPlaceableObject = Instantiate(placeableObjectPrefab);


            }
        }

    }
    

    private void MoveCurrentObjectToMouse()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        RaycastHit hitInfo;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo))
        {
            currentPlaceableObject.transform.position = hitInfo.point;
            currentPlaceableObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, hitInfo.normal);
            currentPlaceableObject.GetComponent<NavMeshObstacle>().enabled = false;


        }
    }

    private void RotateFromMouseWheel()
    {
        Debug.Log(Input.mouseScrollDelta);
        mouseWheelRotation += Input.mouseScrollDelta.y;
        currentPlaceableObject.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, mouseWheelRotation * 90f);
    }

    private void ReleaseIfClicked()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            
            currentPlaceableObject.GetComponent<NavMeshObstacle>().enabled = true;
            print("disabled");
            currentPlaceableObject = null;
            print("removed prefab");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more mathematical approach, and one that you can easily set the grid size for (other than Lews Therin's answer) would be to:

1. Take `position` `mod` `yourGridSize` (say, your grid size is 64 and the position is 144. **then**: 144 `mod` 64 = 16)
2. Take the `mod` result and subtract from position: 144 - 16 = 128
3. Finally, divide the above result by `yourGridSize`: 128 / 64 = 2

Now you know your position is `2` blocks into the grid. Apply this operation for the three axis:

```cs
var yourGridSize = 64;

var currentPosition = currentPlaceableObject.transform.position;
currentPlaceableObject.transform.position = new Vector3(((currentPosition.x - (currentPosition.x % yourGridSize)) / yourGridSize) * yourGridSize,
                                                        ((currentPosition.y - (currentPosition.y % yourGridSize)) / yourGridSize) * yourGridSize,
                                                        ((currentPosition.z - (currentPosition.z % yourGridSize)) / yourGridSize) * yourGridSize);
```

Convoluted? Maybe. Effective? **Heck yes!**

Comment: Don't forget to not-divide if you want coordinates to pave the object *at* in order to position it in the grid.

Comment: @fhc where would I place this in the script, above the update method dosent work as it says it dosent recognize the position variables

Comment: I believe in your `MoveCurrentObjectToMouse()` method, when assigning to `currentPlaceableObject.transform.position`.

Comment: @fhcimolin It wont work, first off the object gets placed like 100 units to my right, and second off it only stays in that place and whenever I try and move it with my mouse it jitters and goes back.   Wait nevermind I just changed the grid size and now it works fine, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can snap to grid in code by simply rounding each axis of the `transform.position`:

```
var currentPosition = transform.position;
transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Round(currentPosition.x),
                                 Mathf.Round(currentPosition.y),
                                 Mathf.Round(currentPosition.z));
```